# Dropzone with Webcam

Tags: webcam, dropzone.js, dropzone

I would like to clarify a doubt about Dropzone.js

Today Dropzone allows you to upload an image from your computer. However, I need the computer's Webcam to be used.

Is it possible to use the webcam to take the photo and Dropzone to store it?

I thank the attention